# logic: how to assert the uniqueness of a predicate (and not the variable)

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Uniqueness is usually asserted as: `∃x(Px & ∀y(Py → y=x))`.
But this only asserts the uniqueness of x. Say I had the phrase "I have only once seen the sun rise". Here I would have to assert the uniqueness of the expression `SEEN(me,sunrise)` to say that `SEEN(me,sunrise)` happened only once. How would I go about doing this? I can't really write something like `∀z ∈ SetOfPredicates, z =  SEEN(x,y)`

Comment: Yes. In second order logic you can quantify over predicates as well  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want to do is model this a different way. For example, you might use a function or predicate symbol to model the number of times a person has seen something. Alternatively, you might use a predicate symbol that states that a person saw something at a particular time, and then you can assert the uniqueness of that time.

You might be able to produce something essentially equivalent to the last statement in some [temporal logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_logic). More dramatically, you could switch to a substructural logic like [linear logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_logic) where there is a difference between something being "true" once and being "true" more than once, i.e. the linear logic equivalent of $A\equiv A\land A$ does *not* hold. It's unlikely that you want to move to these non-standard logics though.